# Amazon Selling Partner API - Upload Product Data

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I use the Selling Partner API for PHP from jlevers
(https://github.com/jlevers/selling-partner-api)

Connection works after a lot of reading posts. I can get orders, order items and so on.

Now I want to try to upload product data to amazon.

Is it possible to upload the product in json format ? Or is it normal that we still upload the product data in xml format?  I cant find a PHP example with json format.

I found this example:
https://spapi.cyou/en/use-case/feeds-api-use-case-guide_2021-06-30.html#xml-feeds

My second question is, if I can get the categories from amazon with a Api call or is it still just an XSD file?

Answer (score 0):

A way i did this in XML format in java is like this:

```
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); //everything is hardcoded except sku & quantity
    stringBuilder.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>").append("\n");
    stringBuilder.append("<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"amzn-envelope.xsd\">").append("\n");
    stringBuilder.append("<Header>").append("\n");
    stringBuilder.append("<DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>").append("\n");
    stringBuilder.append("<MerchantIdentifier>A24AHHJKC9JJQL</MerchantIdentifier>").append("\n");
    stringBuilder.append("</Header>").append("\n");
    stringBuilder.append("<MessageType>Inventory</MessageType>").append("\n");
    stringBuilder.append("<Message>").append("\n");
    stringBuilder.append("<MessageID>1</MessageID>").append("\n");
    stringBuilder.append("<Inventory>").append("\n");
    stringBuilder.append("<SKU>").append(sku).append("</SKU>").append("\n");                          //------>> SKU
    stringBuilder.append("<Quantity>").append(quantity).append("</Quantity>").append("\n");           //------>> Quantity
    stringBuilder.append("</Inventory>").append("\n");
    stringBuilder.append("</Message>").append("\n");
    stringBuilder.append("</AmazonEnvelope>");
```

Only SKU and Quantity are variables and have to be inputted by the program

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can :).
Use `SellingPartnerApi\Api\ListingsV20210801Api` for adding or updating offer/product. To see requirements for this endpoint use `SellingPartnerApi\Api\ProductTypeDefinitionsV20200901Api` from which you will get schema link resource. There are different requirements for each product type.

I created PHP script that will get me link to schema (This is handle method of custom Laravel Artisan command). It might help you :)

```php
$config = new Configuration([
    'lwaClientId' => config('app.amazon_lwa_client_id'),
    'lwaClientSecret' => config('app.amazon_lwa_client_secret'),
    'lwaRefreshToken' => config('app.amazon_refresh_token'),
    'awsAccessKeyId' => config('app.amazon_aws_access_key_id'),
    'awsSecretAccessKey' => config('app.amazon_aws_secret_access_key'),
    'endpoint' => Endpoint::EU,
]);

$apiInstance = new ProductTypeDefinitionsV20200901Api($config);
$product_type = $this->argument('product_type');
$marketplace_ids = $this->argument('marketplace_id');
$seller_id = config('app.amazon_seller_id');
$product_type_version = 'LATEST';
$requirements = 'LISTING';
$requirements_enforced = 'ENFORCED';
$locale = 'pl_PL';

try {
    $result = $apiInstance->getDefinitionsProductType($product_type, $marketplace_ids, $seller_id, $product_type_version, $requirements, $requirements_enforced, $locale);
    $this->info($result->getSchema()->link->resource);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->error('Exception when calling ProductTypeDefinitionsV20200901Api->getDefinitionsProductType: ' .  $e->getMessage());
}
```